# C# SortedSet lack of index retrival O(log[n])

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, collections

I was trying to solve a challenge in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-subarray-sum/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=search) and the solution requires:

- **O(log[n])** item insertion.
- **O(log[n])** item retrieval by index.

For my surprise I realize that there is not Data Structure that support both operations.

Initially, I believe that [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) fulfill all the requirements but NO!

> SortedDictionary has faster insertion and removal operations for unsorted data, **O(log n)** as opposed to **O(n)** for SortedList.

Reading this line suggest that [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) may have what I need but the answer is NO! again

> Another difference between the SortedDictionary and SortedList classes is that SortedList supports efficient indexed retrieval of keys and values through the collections returned by the Keys and Values properties. It is not necessary to regenerate the lists when the properties are accessed, because the lists are just wrappers for the internal arrays of keys and values. The following code shows the use of the Values property for indexed retrieval of values from a sorted list of strings.

They suggest to fully retrieve the collection of Keys using the **ToList()** extension and **BinarySearch()** over the list but this **ToList()** call already causes the performance to be O(n) and there is no point to call **BinarySearch()**.

In the other hand, there is a very popular implementation of the index retrieval **O(log[n])** that consist in adding a field Count to each Node of the Tree that keep track of how many items are in the Subtree rooted at this Node. This field can be updated during Red Black Tree rotation in O(1) and only consume **sizeof(int)** additional memory per Node.

The questions:

> Why this was not implemented like that since the beginning?
>
> What are the cons of having it in the [SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) data structure?

Comment: *They suggest to fully retrieve the collection of Keys using the ToList() extension* They suggest using the properties that wrap the internal arrays... which is O(1). I don't know how you read sth else out of that sentence...

Comment: This sentence is from the MSDN documentation and what I understand is that given that SortedList is implemented using an array (or a list) they can access an item by index in O(1)

Comment: It still does not mean it's O(n). A call to ToList() would just pass the array as well.. Arrays implement IList. And that's exactly what ToList() returns.

Comment: The SortedDictionary is using a Red-Black Tree as the underlying data structure and the ToList() is actually an enumeration of the Tree (I inspected the source code ;-))

Comment: The documentation says : "The following example demonstrates a SortedSet<T> class that is created with the constructor that takes an IComparer<T>".  IComparer uses a Hash so the access time is the same as a dictionary which also uses a hash.

Comment: Key retrieval should be fast always for this Data Structure. In addition, and this is what my post is about, I need to retrieve fast by the index as well.

Comment: Check the difference between the SortedList API and the SortedDictionary API. SortedList have IndexOfKey and IndexOfValue methods and the SortedDictionary don't